# Symfony 3.4.18 + FosUserBundle 2.0 + LexikJWT

Tags: api, angular6, postman, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.4

I want to to configure LexikJWT with fosuserbunle 2.0 but i receive with postman this always

[image]

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        form_login:
            check_path: /api/login_check
            username_parameter: username
            password_parameter: password
            success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            require_previous_session: false
    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        provider: fos_userbundle
        stateless: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
            # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true





access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

i want to work symfony / FosuserBundle with angular 6 i have choosen LexikJWT.
any help please and if someone have a toturial about symfony3/4 and angular 6 you can give it to me please
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your

```
username_parameter: username
password_parameter: password
```

to

```
username_parameter: _username
password_parameter: _password
```